# How to describe range?

Tags: excel, count, sum, range

Inside a function I need to put a range and I know where to start my range but I have to calculate its end. I need range 350 numbers:
Range (A1230:1580).

Is it possible to write `(A1230 till A1230+350)` ?

Comment: @pnuts I guess I took "Inside a function I need to put a range" as vba function.  Though I guess it could be an exsiting function that accepts a range as input...

Answer (score 0):

Yup..

Try `Range("A1230").Resize(351)`

replace `351` with a variable you use in your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

For say SUM, maybe:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1230,,,350+1))
```